# Query is not being executed on time when Tab.Screen component has been called

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, carousel

I have a project where I am using react-navigation and I am implementing a bottom tab like this:

```
 render() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Tab.Navigator>
                <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={this.HomeScreen} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={this.SettingsScreen} />
            </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

..which is calling `this.HomeScreen` in one of the screens and then `this.SettingsScreen` in the other.

Here I will post the code of the first one:

```
HomeScreen({ navigation }) {      
    const restaurants_discounts = this.restaurants_discounts();     
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>                
            <View style={styles.container}>                   
                <ScrollView
                     style={styles.scrollview}
                     scrollEventThrottle={200}
                     directionalLockEnabled={true}>                        
                     {restaurants_discounts}      
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView >
    );
}
```

When the function below is called it has no data to render because `this.state.discounts` is empty since `getDiscounts()` is called later :

```
 restaurants_discounts() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.exampleContainer}>             
            <Carousel
                ref={c => this._slider1Ref = c}
                data={this.state.discounts}
                renderItem={this._renderDiscounts.bind(this)}                   
                ...           
            >
            </Carousel>
        </View>
    );
}


getDiscounts() {   //this is being called after `restaurants_discounts()` has been called 
        var ref = firestore().collection('discounts')
        ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot => {
             var discounts = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => { return { ...doc.data(), discount_id: doc.id } });
             this.setState({
                discounts: discounts                        
             });                
        }));
    }
}
```

`getDiscounts()` gets called in `componentDidMount()`:

```
componentDidMount() {   
   this.getDiscounts();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you only return the component when this.state.discount is defined. For example:

```
    restaurants_discounts() {
        if (this.state.discounts === undefined || this.state.discounts === null) 
            return (<View><Text>Loading...</Text></View>);
        return ( 
            <View style={styles.exampleContainer}>             
                <Carousel
                    ref={c => this._slider1Ref = c}
                    data={this.state.discounts}
                    renderItem={this._renderDiscounts.bind(this)}                   
                    ...           
                >
                </Carousel>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Comment: This will display `Loading...` , so?! I need to display the fetched data . The problem is that it is fetching AFTER render() has been mounted

Comment: i had a typo in the code, fixed it. Should be this.state.discounts

Comment: its not about that, please read my post properly! I NEED TO DISPLAY FETCHED DATA NOT A LOADING ICON

Comment: The code that I have checks for your data (I'm assuming is in the object this.state.discounts). If the data doesn't exist, display the loading message. If it does exist, display your data. This is how React works.

Comment: I know how Reacts work, I am asking why the data is not being displayed (THEY ARE IN STATE) but it seems like I am rendering before I get the data so how should I fix that.

Comment: you are calling componentDidMount(): to get the data, this also means your data isn't there when React first tries to display the component. This will throw an error. The flow is this: React creates/mounts the components, then componentDidMount(): calls the API to get the data (async function). When React tried to create the component with your state variable which doesn't exist at that point. That's why my code checks for it to make sure it's defined. When the data come back from the API, then it will display it correctly.